# Outlook 2011 Keyboard Shortcut for going to Inbox

Tags: keyboard, ms-office

Is there a keyboard shortcut in Outlook for Mac 2011 that allows me to jump back to the main *Inbox* folder? Under my Inbox, I have a long list of folders that spans more than a full screen. If I'm at one of the folders close to the bottom of the list, let's say *Sent Items* and want to quickly go back to the *Inbox* folder, I have to use the mouse to scroll up in the folder list and then click on *Inbox*.

Is there a way to go there faster? I remember there being a shortcut for this on Windows if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a little AppleScript to do this. If you copy it to your "~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/Outlook Script Menu Items" folder you can assign a shortcut key to it using System Preferences/Keyboard.

Works like a charm.

The script is:

```
on run {}   
    tell application "Microsoft Outlook"    
        set selected folder to inbox
    end tell
end run
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a ton!

Comment: To select folders other than the built-ins, you can do: `set selected folder to the folder named "Keep"`

Comment: Can something like this be done for Outlook version 15 (year 2015)?

Comment: Not the same way, since they did away with scripts in the newer version of Outlook. I now use BetterTouchTool to create my shortcut, and I have it execute the same AppleScript.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is any shortcut available for it. But still [here](http://mac2.microsoft.com/help/office/14/en-us/outlook/item/3b58300d-6f02-47f3-b1fc-9cbe8bb4eac7) is a list of shortcuts for your reference.

Comment: Mh, that's too bad. I had a look at the list, but didn't find anything that does what I need. A brief look at the MS forums confirms this, there's more people looking for something similar, but no answers.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the post from [thatdamncat](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/42859/thatdamncat) a little so that it will change to the mail view if the window is not on there. although if you have multiple main windows this may mess with your flow.

```
on run {}
    tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
        tell the first main window
            set view to mail view
        end tell
        set selected folder to inbox
    end tell
end run
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to emulate Outlook for Windows' SHIFT-CTRL-I (Go to Inbox) command and came across this script.  I modified the post from [@greenwar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/10671/greenwar) because it was throwing errors if the main windows was not mail view AND the Inbox was not selected.  Here goes:

```
on run {}
    tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
        if view of the first main window is not equal to "mail view" then
            set view of the first main window to mail view
            if selected folder is not equal to inbox then
                set selected folder to inbox
            end if
        end if
        -- end tell
    end tell
end run
```

I'm still looking for a way to make this a keyboard shortcut **ONLY** when Outlook is running.  I found **[this article](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13916)** on Apple.com but it requires you know the keyboard entry for the script menu.  How the heck do you find that?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> takes you to the inbox
<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> takes you to the calendar
<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> takes you to the address book

Comment: Command-1 takes you to your mail, but only to the last-viewed box, not to the inbox.